# Managing Java EE multi module projects with subversion (without Maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tags, ear

In my company we are dealing with the best structure for a Java EE multimodule project. It's our first multi-module project and we cannot find a clear explanation about this.

We have this SVN repository:

```
project1
  +- branches
  +- tags
  +- trunk
       +- parent_module.ear
       +- module1.jar
       +- module2.war
```

When we create this project in Eclipse (we are NOT using Maven) we get three "independent" projects:

- parent_module.ear: the EAR project
- module1.jar: the jar project (EJB)
- modele2.war: the war project

We don't know if the SVN structure is correct for our purposes. Commiting independent modules is working fine.
But when we release a new version of the project, we want to create a unique TAG (including the head revision of the entire project). But with subclipse we have to create the TAG in every project, and we cannot create the same TAG for different projects.

Is our SVN project tree ok? Or maybe this one is better for our purpose?

```
project1
  +- branches
  +- tags
  +- trunk
       +- parent_module.ear
              +- module1.jar
              +- module2.war
```

and committing to SVN, create tags, etc. outside Eclipse?

Comment: The structure doesn't look bad. If you want to release the whole project, you can create the tag from the trunk folder (using whatever svn client you want to use). If you insist to use eclipse, you can checkout the trunk (not the individual project) and do the tag from there. And I have to say that I personally I would try to use maven :) it already has recipes for releasing projects like this.

Comment: Thanks @Augusto, we've finally decided to use Maven using the same structure